# App config for Cocoa applications?

Tags: macos, cocoa, config

Does anyone know if Cocoa has anything similar to .NET app.config file? I was looking at nib files, but I think it's a bit different?! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Appname-Info.plist which is created by xcode for any new app. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/index.html

You can then access properties using...

```
NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString* property = [bundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"keyname"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using NSUserDefaults which can also be read/written from the command line via the "defaults" command.